# Exception in Riak Java store in bucket

Tags: java, riak

I'm running the following simple java program with riak client 1.4.2, but it does not work. The program only runs for about 3 or 4 iterations and then it fail with an exception.

```
import com.basho.riak.client.IRiakClient;
import com.basho.riak.client.RiakException;
import com.basho.riak.client.RiakFactory;
import com.basho.riak.client.bucket.Bucket;
import com.basho.riak.client.raw.http.HTTPClientConfig;

public class TestRiak {

    private static IRiakClient riakClient;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RiakException {

        HTTPClientConfig config = new HTTPClientConfig.Builder().withPort(10028).build();
        riakClient = RiakFactory.newClient(config);

        for(int i = 0 ; i < 10000 ; i++){
            Bucket bucket = riakClient.fetchBucket("bucket56").execute();
            Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
            pojo.id_2 = "550" + i;
            pojo.value = "val";
            System.out.println(i);
            bucket.store(pojo).execute();
        }
    }
}

import com.basho.riak.client.convert.RiakKey;

public class Pojo{

    @RiakKey
    public String id_2;

    public String value;
}
```

Exception :
  Exception in thread "main" com.basho.riak.client.RiakRetryFailedException: com.basho.riak.client.http.response.RiakResponseRuntimeException: Error:
54767792

```
at com.basho.riak.client.cap.DefaultRetrier.attempt(DefaultRetrier.java:79)
at com.basho.riak.client.cap.DefaultRetrier.attempt(DefaultRetrier.java:81)
at com.basho.riak.client.cap.DefaultRetrier.attempt(DefaultRetrier.java:81)
at com.basho.riak.client.cap.DefaultRetrier.attempt(DefaultRetrier.java:81)
at com.basho.riak.client.cap.DefaultRetrier.attempt(DefaultRetrier.java:53)
at com.basho.riak.client.operations.StoreObject.execute(StoreObject.java:148)
at TEstRiak.main(TEstRiak.java:23)
```

Caused by: com.basho.riak.client.http.response.RiakResponseRuntimeException: Error:
54767792

```
at com.basho.riak.client.http.response.FetchResponse.<init>(FetchResponse.java:121)
at com.basho.riak.client.http.RiakClient.store(RiakClient.java:184)
at com.basho.riak.client.raw.http.HTTPClientAdapter.store(HTTPClientAdapter.java:235)
at com.basho.riak.client.operations.StoreObject$1.call(StoreObject.java:150)
at com.basho.riak.client.operations.StoreObject$1.call(StoreObject.java:148)
at com.basho.riak.client.cap.DefaultRetrier.attempt(DefaultRetrier.java:72)
... 6 more
```

My riak ring has just 1 node, its anti_entropy has turned off and bucket properties are "dw":"quorum", "n_val":3,"pw":0,"r":"quorum","rw":"quorum", "w":"quorum". Any answer for the question would be really appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: in your source, fetchBucket execute every loop.
is there any reason for fetching Bucket every loop?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code (per se - as noted above you really only want to fetch the bucket once); the error message is coming from Riak. Unfortunately, I can't reproduce this. I'd look at the Riak logs.

Comment: Yes, the fetchBucket can add before the loop, but it doesn't make any difference. Same exceptions are thrown. Thank You

Comment: Sometimes there might be an error in my riak node, even when i execute the following query twice i get completely two different results,

 http://localhost:10028/riak/AdjacenceyList?keys=true

keys:["0b774858-fa01-4310-a0ae-357856","cb549553-f9a1-497d-8441-edfeff","8dfda62b-8903-4313-ba04-c99697","89db11dc-3776-44ef-b197-e45f42"] 

"keys":["0b774858-fa01-4310-a0ae-357856"]

I took above two results by just executing the same query one after the other. If i execute it again then i get the first result again and after couple of seconds it gives the second result again. Any suggestions..?

Comment: 1. What version of Riak are you running?  

2. How did you install it?

3. Can you upload Riak's console.log file to a gist or something similar?

Comment: Sure, my riak version is 1.4.6 and I donwloaded it from http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/downloads/. Previously there was a 32 bit version for ubuntu, i downloaded that. I installed riak by following the instructions in here, http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/quickstart/ . And this is my console.log output and config file https://gist.github.com/samii89/8436066. Thank you